# Fill empty lines in specific column with values

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I have data of the following format:

```
2342 1
6473 2
7463 2
3647
2734 1
9343
```

The lines that do not have a value in the 2nd column are empty in that spot (i.e. there is no space, tab etc.). I am looking for a simple command that puts a '-9' in the open places of column 2.

(Basically an `awk` command that checks if the line is non-zero in column 2, and then add '-9' if that's the case should do it I'd say..)

Extended example (data with more columns, some of which containing missings). I only want to add '-9' to the last column (i.e. the other columns are allowed to have missings).

```
2342 0 12 1
6473   13 2
7463 0 14 2
3647 0  
2734 0    1
9343 0 16
```

Comment: Something like: `awk '{if (foo[$2]!=1) || (foo[$2]!=2); then {print "-9"}}' foo`, which clearly doesn't work.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to run `kill -9 pid`  which is wrong.  Use `kill -l` to see all available signals en what you need to use instead.

Comment: How are your fields separated? Are they always at fixed offsets within the line (0, 5, 7, 10)?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, Space delimited. However, if the last column doesn't contain a value it also doesn't have a space (i.e. those lines end after the last real value). I hope it's clear what I'm trying to say here.

Comment: Does your 5th line in your second example have fields 1, 2, 3 (fields separated by any amount of space), 1, 2, 4 (fixed width fields), or 1, 2, 6 (fields separated by one space, and there are 4 spaces between `0` and `1`) (same goes for the 2nd line).

Comment: The 5th line has fields 1, 2, 4 (fixed width fields)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is expressed in fixed width columns, you could do:

For the first case:

```
sed 's/^.\{4\}$/& -9/'
```

(add `" -9"` to lines of 4 characters).

For the second case:

```
sed -e '/.\{11\}/b' -e 's/$/          /;s/\(.\{10\}\).*/\1-9/'
```

(add up to 10 spaces and -9 to lines of less than 11 characters).

Generally, to parse lines with fixed width fields, see the `FIELDWIDTHS` special variable of GNU `awk`.

Comment: `add up to 10 spaces` Doesn't it add 10 spaces everytime?

Comment: @User112638726, no, it adds 10 spaces (first s command), then only retains the first 10 characters. So for empty lines, it adds 10 spaces, and for lines with 9 characters, it adds one.

Comment: Oh right, i thought you were documenting what the sed was doing, not the end result.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed

```
sed ':;s/^.\{0,9\}$/& /;t;s/^.\{10\}$/&-9/' file
```

Adds one space as long a the number of characters is below ten using test `t`.
Then replaces lines with ten character with themselves and `-9.`

Comment: Defining an empty label works by accident in GNU sed, I would advise against doing it. `t` or `b` without a label are meant to jump to the end (start the next cycle), and is documented as such even in GNU sed. POSIXly: `sed -e :1 -e 's/^.\{0,9\}$/& /;t1' -e 's/^.\{10\}$/&-9/'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yep, i remembered you telling me last time which is why i specified GNU. I thought it was supposed to work that way though in GNU.

Comment: It's not supposed to work that way, it just works by accident, GNU sed doesn't check for an empty label on ":" and upon t/b looks in the list of defined labels first before considering an empty  label as the special case it's meant to be. It is not documented to work that way. It may not work that way in future versions.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks,I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Dammit @StéphaneChazelas, you've no idea how many of my [code-golf answers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70809/11259) you've screwed up with this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this `awk` with your first example:

```
awk 'NF == 1 { $2 = -9; } 1' file
```

As mentioned in other posts with `gawk` you can use `FIELDWIDTHS`, so you can try this with your second one:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "4 1 1 1 2 1 1"} { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if ($i == "") { if (i == 7) $i = "-9"; else $i = " "; } } printf("%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $3, $5, $7); }' file
```

Comment: Thanks @taliezin, for the example this works fine. However, I think it won't work properly if my file has multiple columns that may contain missings as well..

Comment: This is for your given example, can you add different example and I'll delete answer as inappropriate? And with more columns you can not determine which column is missing.

Comment: I added an extended data example. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work anymore in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
perl -ane 'if(!$F[1]){print $F[0]," -9\n"}else{print $_;}'
```

This command reads your input line-wise and prints a "-9" in the second column, if it is empty.

```
echo "2342 1
6473 2
7463 2
3647
2734 1
9343" | perl -ane 'if(!$F[1]){print $F[0]," -9\n"}else{print $_;}'

2342 1
6473 2
7463 2
3647 -9
2734 1
9343 -9
```